# Actual property name on REQUIRED_CHILDREN connetion

Tags: relay

In relay, when using `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` like so:

```
   return [{
      type: 'REQUIRED_CHILDREN',
      children: [
        Relay.QL`
          fragment on Payload {
            myConnection (first: 50) {
              edges {
                node {
                  ${fragment}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `
      ]
    }]
```

and reading off the response through the `onSuccess` callback:

```
Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
  new AboveMutation({  }), { onFailure, onSuccess }
)
```

the response turns the property `myConnection` into a hashed name (i.e. `__myConnection652K`), which presumably is used to prevent connection/list conflicts inside the relay store.

However, since this is a `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` and I'm manually reading `myConnection`, it just prevents access to it.

Is there an way to get the actual property names when using the onSuccess callback?

Comment: Using `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` means you're not going to store the results. How about using a `GraphQLList` type instead of connection type? You can pass `first` as an argument for the mutation!

Answer (score 0):

Just as Ahmad wrote: using `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` means you're not going to store the results. The consequence of it is that data supplied to the callback is in raw shape (nearly as it came from server) and [data masking](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/thinking-in-relay.html#data-masking) does not applies.

Despite not storing the data, it seems to be no reason (though core team member's opinion would be certainly more appropriate here) not to convert it to *client style* shape. This is the newest type of mutation, so there is a chance such feature was accidentally omitted. This is normal that queries are transformed to the *server style* shape, the opposite transformation could take place as well. However until now is has not been needed - while saving the data to the store and updating components props, transformation was made meanwhile. Currently most of Relay team is highly focused on rewriting much of the implementation, so I would not expect this issue to be improved very soon.

So again, solution proposed by Ahmed to **convert type to `GraphQLList` seems to be the easiest and most reliable**. If for any reason you want to stand by connection, there is an option to take `GraphQL fragment` supplied as `children` (actually its parsed form stored in `__cachedFragment__` attribute of that original fragment) and traverse it to obtain the `serializationKey` for desired field (eg `__myConnection652K`).